# Font changes mid sentence in webpage despite there being no style change in the HTML. Why?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to set up a wordpress blog (in Swedish unfortunately) and in one post two people, independent of each other, noticed that the font is changing mid sentence:

[image: Wrong font]

They both run windows 7 with Chrome, I've tried to replicate this font change on my linux, mac and iOS systems but for me it renderers correctly. On Ubuntu with latest firefox, for example, the font stays the same:

[image: correct font]

**Why this strange behaviour and what could I do to fix it? I don't really know where to start...**

The post with the paragraph is [here](http://groggbloggen.se/kalla-kriget/). This is the HTML behind the paragraph rendering incorrectly:

```
<p><strong>Rasmus:</strong> Groggen smakar frihet kamrat! 
Eller, nä&#8230; det smakar vodka — och — Coca-Cola, varken
mer eller mindre. Hade varit gott med lime i, men då är det 
ju ingen grogg längre&#8230;</p>
```

The font is the [Cardo font](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cardo) that resides on Google fonts.

I would be grateful for any tips on to start debugging this!

Comment: Weird. Looks fine for me in Chrome on OS X. Can you try selecting the offending paragraph and inspecting it, to see whether it has become a separate HTML element for some reason? Do you have some JavaScript running operations on the text after the document has loaded?

Comment: Nope, no javascript. The HTML looks the same in the rendered document (looking at it with firebug). Currently I'm not on a system where I havve been able to replicate the "bug". Could it be some kind of clash because the font does not support `&#8230;` elipsis(...) or the em dash?

Comment: It's the most likely explanation, although I can't see why it should result in this behaviour. Seems like a browser-side bug. What version of Chrome is that?

Comment: Right now I don't know, I'll ask them. But I guess it is the latest stable release...

Comment: Can you please try whether it works better with `&hellip;`? `&8320;` seems like it's a ISO-8859-1 entity and your page is UTF-8. It could be that that is causing the weirdness (would still be a browser bug tho)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I've added it but my windows 7 friends are currently offline. Thanks for the tip, I'll report back tomorrow! :)

Comment: Yeah, do! Really interested to see what caused this. Maybe @JHuangweb can try it in the meantime. (I can't see the problem on my machine).

Comment: @Pekka웃 One guy was awake, &hellip; did not solve the problem but replacing wiith ... (three single dots) did. Still don't know what the original problem was, but it does sound like a bit of a browser bug...

Comment: Weird. Then it's a bug either with Chrome, or the Google Font (but seeing as it *does* work in so many other browsers, the latter seems unlikely.) I'd be happy to put a bounty on the question later (I think it has to be 24 hours old for it to be possible).

Comment: The linked page where the problem appears has been edited so that the problem is gone (the ellipsis has been replaced by three dots). So this part of the question is now misleading.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chrome 31 on Win 7 when testing with Google-hosted Cardo, `body { font-family: Cardo, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif }` and the markup in the question. And the page mentioned in the question was edited so that the problem was removed...

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Now reverted the page back to the "faulty" version and ran it through cross browser rendering at [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/http://groggbloggen.se/kalla-kriget) and that replicated the error. See for example for [Chrome 29 on windows 2008](http://browsershots.org/screenshots/9def206bf68be95232174dadc28133ba).

Comment: @Pekka웃 More weirdness. If I just "cut out" the faulty paragraph it renderers correctly in chrome 29. [source](http://sumsar.net/files/font_bug.html) and [browsershot](http://browsershots.org/screenshots/7f452f5535c2e30e94b9abe79ac390cd)

Comment: Yet another weirdness: if you modify the window width, causing line length to vary, the amount of text in wrong font changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky bug in font handling in Chrome. There are several workarounds, but it is not clear what exactly triggers the bug, so there is no guarantee that the workarounds work in all situations.

The following document triggers the bug, in Chrome 31 on Win 7:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Font changes mid sentence</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo'
     rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
body { font-family: Cardo, Courier New, monospace }
p { text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; }
</style>
<p><strong>Rasmus:</strong> Groggen smakar frihet kamrat! 
Eller, nä&#8230; det smakar vodka — och — Coca-Cola, varken
mer eller mindre. Hade varit gott med lime i, men då är det 
ju ingen grogg längre&#8230;</p>
```

Sample rendering:

[image]

Thus, everythig from the string “nä…” till the end of the line is in the secondary font (here Courier New, for clarity). The same applies to the entire line containing the second occurrence of “…”.

The [character repertoire of Cardo](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cardo) does not contain “…”, for some odd reason. So it is natural that the browser picks that character from another font; this happens on other browsers as well. But Chrome goes all wrong in font handling, so that it uses a fallback font also for subsequent characters, forward to the end of the line, or backward to the start of the line. (There is probably variation in this.)

Removing `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` makes the problem disappear, so this apparently has something to do with kerning or ligatures. This hypothesis is supported by the observation that another way to make the problem go away is to wrap the ellipsis character in an element of its own, like `<span>&#8230;</span>`.

And, of course, using three periods “...” instead of the ellipsis “…” avoids triggering the bug. But the bug is probably of a more general nature and may be triggered by various characters in text when they are not present in the primary font being used.

It does not matter how the ellipsis “…” is represented in HTML (as such vs. numeric reference vs. named reference).

Comment: So actually not a bug on my end, nice to hear! I revert the site back to the working version. If someone wants to know the text example you have is a review of the Vodka-n-Cola grog (aka the cold war)

Answer (score 0):

On that paragraph, change `nä…` to `nä...`.  The three dots were unrecognizable characters within your selected font family, thus throwing it off and enforcing a default rendering.

Your font-family is set to `"Cardo", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif`  When `nä…` was detected, Cardo did not recognize it and changed it to it's second best option, Helvetica, which is expected.

If you want to enforce the Cardo font at all cost, then you can just use `font-family: Cardo`.  But, I recommend against this for various reasons.

Comment: But that would be a bug in whatever browser is being used, no?

Comment: @Pekka웃, it's not a bug.  When OP pasted nä…, the last three "…" are unrecognizable.  Not sure where it was cut and pasted from.

Comment: But why would it be expected behaviour for the browser to change the font style when it runs into an invalid character?

Comment: Yeah, but it is still strange that it affects the characters following ... , right?

Comment: @RasmusBååth, is see it now and then.  It has to do with differences in languages of the copied source and pasted output.  Similar issue here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/i-copied-foreign-language-korean-and-wish-to-paste/e3f4feaa-52f1-4275-9536-7fd53e1e5cb8

Comment: As said, it would *not* be the expected behaviour for a browser to work this way even if the character were actually invalid. It isn't, though. It is * correctly rendered* in my Chrome on OS X, for example. This is not a resolution,  nor is it even a correct diagnosis of the problem.

Comment: @Pekka웃 edited my answer above.  Hope that makes more sense.  OP's font-family was set to nä…"Cardo", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif.  Cardo didn't recognize the text and therefore Helvetica rendered.

Comment: But Cardo *does* render the ellipsis in my Chrome: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CuFuQ.png The font doesn't seem to be the reason here. But I think you're right in that it gets thrown off, hold on...

Comment: It's only shown in view source, http://i.imgur.com/WmulHbs.png I'm on Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63

Comment: 31.0.1650.63 on OS X here, and it shows up OK on the page and in view source. Weird. I'm thinking this is a bug in Chrome because the numeric entity `&8320;` is somehow connected to ISO-8859-1, and the page is UTF-8. Not sure. Does it work for you if you change `&8320;` to `&hellip;` in Firebug?